# Flash CS5 not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: flash, debugging, breakpoints

This problem has been bothering me for four days now with no glimpse of a solution. All of a sudden when I'm working on Flash CS5 it stopped stopping at breakpoints I set when I'm debugging. So far I have tried the following,

- Reinstalling Flash.
- Uninstall and reinstalling Flash.
- Remove the whole adobe suite and reinstalling.
- Reinstalling windows.(Formatted HD, sounds ridiculous I know :) Still, the problem prevails. I have been working with this copy of Flash CS5 for about four months with no problems at all.)
- Tried connecting to the debugger or the profiler through localhost and the IP 127.0.0.1.
- Unistalled Flash player and reinstalled.
- Installed the latest Flash player.

All leading to dead ends!

When I installed the same copy on one of colleague's PC, IT WORKS just fine!

Here is a video of the bug I recorded a few days ago. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4LdQ8wRECY

Comment: I see you are getting a security error with a cross domain file from adobe. Maybe try to resolve all the issues with that first

Comment: @The_asMan There aren't any. Actually despite this weird thing I continued my work and now the compiled swf act funny from time to time.

Comment: I know this may sound odd but sometimes a privately scoped method will mess up my break points on event call backs. Its just a shot but try changing it to public. I know it has nothing to do with it but can't hurt

Comment: @The_asMan Well, it's working fine on some projects and some it won't. I cannot yet pinpoint to any sort of action that could be the cause of this because it is completely random.

Comment: Hey have you tried this? flash.debugger.enterDebugger();

Comment: are you pressing cntrl+shift+enter

Comment: haha... indeed I am. I have been doing flash development for 5 years now. -_-

Comment: well, it does not matter much now cause the project i was working on is over and i somehow made it using plenty of reading and trace statements. however, it has come up again with another project i'm working with using google maps api. same scene where the code won't just simply stop at breakpoints when debugging but flash.debug.enterDebugger() is working fine.

Comment: Yeah this is an odd one. There must be a setting somewhere that either turned off break points or maybe reassigned loading the debugger. OOOO wait a minute. Have you installed the debugger version in the browser you are using? What browser are you using?

Comment: It seems this is specific to whatever the project files(.fla) that causes this issue. I have moved on to CS 5.5 and working on many projects and the new projects work well. I had to do some code modifications to the project I was referring to earlier and in CS 5.5 the issue remains the same. I do remind you, I did this... "Reinstalling windows" So basically we have a some sort of a corrupted .fla which some how causes the Flash to go nuts when we open it and keeps on ignoring breakpoints. Basically when that happens I simply restart my laptop, but this is no way a solid solution.

Comment: Are you trying to debug in IE or FireFox

Comment: go here and validate you are running the debug version. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html I know you said re-installs of everything, but it could be possible the normal player got installed with other software.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the debugger.  Maybe they're somehow related.

For me, the debugger was stopping at the break points.  However, it was NOT showing the yellow arrow, so I could not tell where the code flow was when stepping forward.

Eventually, one of the tech support guys discovered that the problem was somehow linked to my PC user profile.  He created a new user profile for me and then copied all of my other "stuff" over.

This worked well... for three days.  However, this happened to me AGAIN today!  I was debugging just fine.  I made a change, fired up the debugger, and lost my arrows.  I tried rebooting, but they're still gone.

I HATE CS5.  It's a total piece of crap!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's a problem I recently ran into as well and found there's a simple solution to it.

Go to Window > Debug and open the Debug panel.  This panel has to be opened at some point during your Flash session in order to display when the debugger runs.  When you create a new project it's opened by default, but on subsequent openings of Flash it doesn't always open automatically, and needs to be opened manually.  This will reinstate breakpoints and stepping.